# Allow one checkbox in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, checkbox

I'm using AngularJS and filter option, like this:

```
  // Functions - Definitions
  function filterByCategory(box) {
    return (this.filter[box.cat1] || this.filter[box.videoYear] || noFilter(this.filter))? 'show':'not-click';
  }

  function filterByYear(box) {
    return (this.filter[box.videoYear] || this.filter[box.cat1] || noFilter(this.filter))? 'year':'not-year';
  }

  function getCategories() {
    return (self.boxes || []).
    map(function (box) { return box.cat1; }).
    filter(function (box, idx, arr) { return arr.indexOf(box) === idx; });
  }

  function getYear() {
    return (self.boxes || []).
    map(function (box) { return box.videoYear; }).
    filter(function (box, idx, arr) { return arr.indexOf(box) === idx; });
  }

  function noFilter(filterObj) {
   return Object.
   keys(filterObj).
   every(function (key) { return !filterObj[key]; });
 }
```

And this is my HTML:

```
   <li ng-repeat="cat in ctrl.getCategories()">
          <input type="checkbox" name="{{cat}}" ng-model="ctrl.filter[cat]" id='{{$index}}' class='chk-btn styled-checkbox' checked/>
          <label for='{{$index}}'>{{cat}}</label>
        </li>
```

These codes works good on the page. When I click an item in checkbox, it added class to my list:

```
<div data-toggle="modal" data-target="#dialogTestDialog{{$index}}" ng-click="Clear()" class="grid-item box {{box.class}} {{ctrl.filterByYear(box)}} {{ctrl.filterByCategory(box)}}"  ng-style="{'background-color': '#'+box.colorCode}">
```

Ok, but I've got a little problem. Now, I can select all items but it should be select one item in checkbox list and remove/add class by related.

How can I do it?

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wYfs4/831/)**

Comment: Why not radio button?

Comment: Because radio button -I don't know why- not working in my structure.

Comment: can you make live demo for this ?

Comment: Here is my sample: http://jsfiddle.net/wYfs4/831/

Comment: Follow @MaximShoustin and use radio buttons. It's working in your structure and is exactly what you try to build by your own. There is no reason using checkbox with javascript instead of radio buttons in your case. if you want the design of a checkbox rather than the look of a radio button use CSS to style the element

Comment: @JoshuaK as you can see, radio buttons not working on the demo.

Comment: No problem. works for me... [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kasalop/wYfs4/835/). I'll write an answer. gimme a sec

Answer (score 0):

Just use html radio-buttons. Radio buttons are like checkboxes but you can only select one at the same time.

Different from checkboxes radio buttons are assigning a value to the model instead of true / false. So you have to make slightly changes to your code.

First: add a `value` attribute to the radio buttons and assign the category.
Second: change self.filter from an object to a string.
Third: change the filterByCategory method to match against a string and not an object.

That's all.

All in all:

**Changed html part:**

```
<label>
  <input type="radio" name="groupCat" value="{{category}}" ng-model="ctrl.filter" />
  {{ category }}
</label>
```

**Changed js part:**

```
// Variables - Public
self.filter = '';
...
// Functions - Definitions
function filterByCategory(wine) {
    return (self.filter == wine.category)? 'show':'hide';
}
```

Working fiddle can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Kasalop/wYfs4/835/)